# Access-Calculated Field- Nested IIF

Tags: ms-access, calculated-field, iif-function

I am a newbie, I need help understanding what I am doing incorrectly. I have a calculated field in the table and the expression I have entered is pasted below I am getting an invalid syntax:-

```sql
IIf([JPP-JPA_Received_Date]<=[JPP-JPA_Due_Date],"On Time", IIf([JPP-JPA_Received_Date]>[JPP-JPA_Due_Date],"Late", IIf([JPP-JPA_Received_Date],Is Null, AND IIF([JPP-JPA_Due_Date]<Date(),"Over Due"))))
```

Comment: Avoid calculated table fields. Use a _select query_ for that.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things are a little off.

The part where you are checking if [JPP-JPA_Received_Date] is null AND the [Jpp-JPA_Due Date] is prior to today, should all be contained in the condition section of a single `Iif` function.

You also may need to wrap each instance of `[JPP-JPA_Received_Date]` in an `Nz()` function. That's because if it is null, Access might get tripped up on expressions like Null <= Due Date.

Finally, I'd recommend the `SWITCH` function. It does something similar to nested if statements, but it's a little easier to follow.

Comment: Excellent answer by Bryan Rock.  A couple comments over it. The Nz() function in SQL always returns a string datatype: be careful with this when including it in other expressions, and in particular in UNIONs. The Switch() function is far more readable than nested Iif() functions. However, Switch() evaluates ALL its argument expressions, even the ones that are not going to be returned, while Iif() does not: this may lead to a crash when an expression that you thought would not be evaluated by Switch() is actually evaluated.

Comment: Thanks for your response, however I had tried the SWITCH function via query it worked  The query with switch generates report for each project per member response if late or on time. I was adding the expression in the table as calculated field so I could count   the result for each Member A,B,C how many Late and On time response and then get average for overall metric.

Comment: For the Metrics that I mentioned above I tried the count on the query it worked  In the query I added Member-Total Group By  JPP_JPA_Response_Status: Switch([JPP-JPA_Received_Date]<=[JPP-JPA_Due_Date],"On Time",[JPP-JPA_Received_Date]>[JPP-JPA_Due_Date],"Late",[JPP-JPA_Received_Date] Is Null And [JPP-JPA_Due_Date]<Date(),"Over Due")-Total-Group by

Comment: JPP_JPA_Response_Status Count: Count(Switch([JPP-JPA_Received_Date]<=[JPP-JPA_Due_Date],"On Time",[JPP-JPA_Received_Date]>[JPP-JPA_Due_Date],"Late",[JPP-JPA_Received_Date] Is Null And [JPP-JPA_Due_Date]<Date(),"Over Due")) Total: Expression.  When I run the query it gives me Member A Late 6 On Time 13 (which is for multiple years) but how can I add start date and end date so it selects only those that are in the user entered date range. I have the field JPP-JPA_Due_Date that should be used to refer the start /End date range